# Quiero mover el icono de la bolsa (que es el de carrito), que se encuentra en el header de mi tienda online. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce/Wordpress. Muy buenas a todos, el problema es que quiero mover el icono del carrito (que es una bolsa) hacia abajo y hacia la izquierda, para poder alinearlo con el logo y el icono de menú que está a la izquierda. Lo pregunto aquí porque no existe la opción para moverlo, así que tal vez con algún CSS adicional se puede configurar manualmente su posicionamiento. Dejare aquí un screenshot de como se ve: https://ibb.co/Dg2cSGN
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Para saber que estilo de CSS está aplicando a esos elementos puedes visualizalo con la consola del navegador (en Chrome es Ctrl+Shift+C) seleccionas el elemento que quieres inspeccionar, en tu caso seria ese icono y verás a la derecha en la consola del navegador varias pestañas ( te pongo el ejemplo de usar google Chrome). Por defecto verás la pestaña Elements donde aparecerá todo el codigo html. Habrá otra subseccion a la derecha (Styles,computed,Layout, etc) en la subsección de styles puedes ver el CSS que se está aplicando al elemento que has seleccionado (el icono que comentas), el problema suele ser que wordpress aplica muchos estilos desde diferentes sitios. Para poder ver la prioridad de estilos y cual tiene aplicado tienes que ir a la subsección Computed donde te muestra todas las propiedades del elemento y los estilos CSS que tiene aplicados, aparecerán varias lineas, la priodidad la tiene el elemento que haya más arriba. Aquí tienes la documentación de google chrome https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference. Una vez que identificas cual de los estilos tiene aplicado ese elemento tienes que ver de donde viene en wordpress, si lo aplica el tema, el builder o el css personalizado. El css tiene una estructura de preferencias que debes conocer para poder sobreescribir esa propiedad que te está dando problemas de la manera correcta, aquí tienes la información de como funcionan las preferencias de propiedad de CSS https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp
Seguramente puedas aplicar un margin-top para bajar el elemento hacia abajo y un margin-right para mover el elemento a la derecha pero primero debes saber que clase o identificador tiene tu icono. Aqui tienes la guia de CSS para aprender más https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp